# R: create new dataframe using id and record frequency

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, count, frequency

For example, I have a table like below:

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | cat | 0 | dog | 0 |
| 1234 | 0 | new | dog | 0 |
| 5678 | 0 | new | dog | hi |
| 0101 | cat | 0 | 0 | hi |

How do I get a table like this:

| ID | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | cat |
| 1234 | dog |
| 1234 | new |
| 1234 | dog |
| 5678 | new |
| 5678 | dog |
| 5678 | hi |
| 0101 | cat |
| 0101 | hi |

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 1):

This could simply be written as:

```
pivot_longer(`is.na<-`(df, df==0), -ID, values_to = "word",values_drop_na = TRUE)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  ID    name  word 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1234  A     cat  
2 1234  C     dog  
3 1234  B     new  
4 1234  C     dog  
5 5678  B     new  
6 5678  C     dog  
7 5678  D     hi   
8 0101  A     cat  
9 0101  D     hi
```

if you want to use pipes:

```
df %>%
  `is.na<-`(df==0) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "word", values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

For base R, if you dont care about the ordering of the results(of course you could order them) Then you could use:

```
na.omit(cbind(df[1], stack(`is.na<-`(df, df==0), -1)))
     ID values ind
1  1234    cat   A
4  0101    cat   A
6  1234    new   B
7  5678    new   B
9  1234    dog   C
10 1234    dog   C
11 5678    dog   C
15 5678     hi   D
16 0101     hi   D
```

Comment: Instead of writing "`is.na<-`(df==0)"  I would use `dplyr::na_if`. It's more legible.